# Can't scrape next page contents using Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-shell

**I want to scrape the contents from the next pages too but it didn't go to the next page. My code is:**

```
import scrapy
class AggregatorSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'aggregator'
allowed_domains = ['startech.com.bd/component/processor']
start_urls = ['https://startech.com.bd/component/processor']

def parse(self, response):
    processor_details = response.xpath('//*[@class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 product-layout grid"]')
    for processor in processor_details:
        name = processor.xpath('.//h4/a/text()').extract_first()
        price = processor.xpath('.//*[@class="price space-between"]/span/text()').extract_first()
        print ('\n')
        print (name)
        print (price)
        print ('\n')
    next_page_url = response.xpath('//*[@class="pagination"]/li/a/@href').extract_first()
    # absolute_next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
    yield scrapy.Request(next_page_url)
```

I didn't use the urljoin because the next_page_url is giving me the whole url. I also tried the ***dont_filter=true*** argument in the yield function which gives me an infinite loop through the 1st page. The message I'm getting from the terminal is ***[scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.startech.com.bd': https://www.startech.com.bd/component/processor?page=2>***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your `allowed_domains` variable is wrong, use `allowed_domains = ['www.startech.com.bd']` instead [(see the doc)](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=allowed_domains#scrapy.spiders.Spider.allowed_domains).

You can also modify your next page selector in order to avoid going to page one again:

```
import scrapy
class AggregatorSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'aggregator'
    allowed_domains = ['www.startech.com.bd']
    start_urls = ['https://startech.com.bd/component/processor']

    def parse(self, response):
        processor_details = response.xpath('//*[@class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 product-layout grid"]')
        for processor in processor_details:
            name = processor.xpath('.//h4/a/text()').extract_first()
            price = processor.xpath('.//*[@class="price space-between"]/span/text()').extract_first()
            yield({'name': name, 'price': price})
        next_page_url = response.css('.pagination li:last-child a::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if next_page_url:
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page_url)
```

Comment: I changed the allowed domain name, now it goes through the 2nd page but it's not stopping after the 2nd page, it again crawled the 1st page and shows the same things twice.

Comment: This is because of your `next_page_url` variable, you take the first link in the pagination

Comment: so what should I do in this case?

Comment: Both the link has the same value

Comment: Can you tell me about any resource where I can learn more about this css or xpath selector briefly.Thank you.